# how to have 2 instances of the same plugin on octobercms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I a trying out a proof of concept with octobercms I was wondering if you could have 2 instances of the same plugin for example blog plugin one say for male blogs and one for female blogs it does not necessarely need to be the blog plugin but any plugin that could be installed twice, my first thought was to extend the first plugin to the second would this be the correct way to implement such an idea

Comment: hmm you can just make 1 plugin rename plugin name, namespaces etc.. an you have exact same plugin

Comment: the only problem with that is that if say plugin a gets updated then plugin b will need to be manually updated

Comment: there is no easy solution for this i guess, you need to fins some work flow for this, dynamically change name spaces etc some king of script etc..